# GWT application run without browser plugin

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, plugins, browser

How can I run gwt application without any browser plugins?

Comment: if you are talking about development the new superdev mode might help you: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode

Comment: You don't run GWT app with any browser plugin. You only need browser plugin for debugging. Just run the app and point your browser to the URL the Google Eclipse project has created on jetty for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to deploy it into a server (such as Tomcat or Jetty) and run it from there. this is called [Production Mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted#compile).

You can check The Official [GWT tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/) for more info.